# How to link family-members on SENTRI application

Tags: usa, mexico, fees-and-charges, sentri

I am in the process of applying for SENTRI passes for my family (myself, wife, 4 children).  On [this CBP help page](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/sentri/how-apply-sentri/non-refundable-application-fee) it says:

> Application Fee:  $25.00 per person (**or a maximum of $50.00 for husband, wife and minor children**)
>   Fingerprint Fee:    $14.50 (applicants 14 years of age and older)
>   System Cost Fee:    $82.75 per person (**or a maximum of $165.50 for a husband, wife and minor children**)
>   Total Fee:  $122.25 per person

I am aware I need to create an entirely separate login and application for all 6 members of my family, however after completing the first one I don't see where I am presented the option to link family member applications in order to have the application cost limited based on the parts I've bolded above.

How do I ensure I only pay the maximum $50 application and $165.50 system cost for my family SENTRI application?

Comment: Now that is a question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know the answer now.  I wanted to complete all the applications before paying, so I filled them all in.  I noticed that the payment information for my children said $0, whereas for myself and my wife it said $25 (application fee).  I gather it gives the cost based on *age* not on whether you are linked to someone else's application.

[image]

I hit Submit Application here and it tells me the application is in progress, same as it did for my wife and me, but without requiring CC information first.

[image]

So it appears now I'll pay the $82.75 each for my wife and me, and $14.50 each for the two of us plus my two eldest children as they're over 14.  Way better than $122.25 each for 6 of us.